# How to disable scrollbar for navbar in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

There is a page template containing a navigation bar and content in separate blocks. When the page overflows, a scrollbar appears in the content that hits the navbar. The scrollbar itself is needed, but only inside the content, is it possible to display it after the navbar?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Asd</title> 
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar">
      <!-- My navbar  -->
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <!-- Content -->
    </div>

  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: a scrollbar is always part of that element. You only possible way would to write your own custom scrollbar with JS

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after. Your nav stays the same height (yellow in my example) but the content inside the content class has a scroll bar if it has lots of content.

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
.navbar{
width:100%;
height:50px;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:yellow;
}
.content{
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background:#ccc;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Asd</title> 
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar">
      <!-- Моя навигационная панель  -->
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh ante, fringilla ac risus et, porta interdum magna. Suspendisse lacinia nisl in libero hendrerit blandit. Pellentesque facilisis bibendum mauris, eu vestibulum risus aliquet a. Ut quis sapien turpis. Vivamus velit libero, convallis a mollis eget, pretium eu ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi metus ipsum, vehicula placerat egestas a, aliquam nec augue. Aliquam tincidunt purus odio, ac gravida velit sagittis varius. Vivamus at magna et est convallis posuere a ut libero. Mauris at lacus diam. Nam iaculis magna turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac eros tortor.</p>
<p>Quisque vitae leo sed velit semper placerat. Aenean non fringilla urna, sit amet luctus dolor. Nam quis pulvinar eros, ac egestas sapien. Cras ultricies dictum hendrerit. Sed lorem enim, egestas in facilisis nec, hendrerit id orci. Vivamus volutpat dolor vitae massa luctus auctor. Mauris tempor lectus placerat, euismod turpis id, cursus nisl. Vivamus at elit euismod, semper dui et, dapibus odio. Morbi rhoncus lectus justo, id volutpat orci sollicitudin in. Proin felis augue, lacinia et varius eu, faucibus ac velit. Vestibulum cursus, tortor id auctor ullamcorper, dui neque vehicula eros, at vulputate lectus nisi eu arcu. Proin ac euismod lectus. Nam sollicitudin ullamcorper turpis, eu rutrum felis condimentum eu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Praesent sollicitudin eu nisi sit amet pharetra. Sed pellentesque lacinia placerat. Suspendisse quis magna non dui fringilla tristique. Donec feugiat vel elit at viverra. Pellentesque eu convallis mi. Nam id mi egestas, tempor eros vitae, aliquet eros. Pellentesque nisi mauris, mollis quis sapien ut, faucibus lobortis enim.</p>
<p>Quisque rhoncus odio a sapien tristique porttitor. Aliquam dapibus ultricies dolor ac efficitur. Donec vel ullamcorper metus, eu tincidunt augue. Cras facilisis faucibus turpis nec elementum. Nullam eu venenatis turpis, in molestie libero. Etiam a leo vel nisl varius semper eu a metus. Phasellus nec lacinia dolor. Fusce imperdiet lorem quis hendrerit sagittis.</p>
<p>Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer et efficitur nisl, in pulvinar quam. Aenean vehicula nulla nulla, sit amet imperdiet metus aliquet nec. Duis in purus ultricies, ultrices sapien nec, venenatis enim. Cras iaculis tortor molestie, vehicula risus vitae, egestas erat. Fusce ut ornare nunc, fringilla vehicula ante. Fusce porttitor et tellus sed accumsan. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam ipsum ex, sollicitudin quis mi sed, dignissim dictum leo. Suspendisse lobortis urna vel feugiat maximus. Donec eros nunc, cursus at dui vitae, mattis ullamcorper sem. Nulla vel nisi sit amet enim rutrum ornare et ac ante. Sed in magna vel mauris porttitor maximus. Nam bibendum, quam non efficitur luctus, mauris nunc blandit purus, id tempor orci mauris vel risus. Donec non dignissim mauris.</p>
<p>Integer cursus ex a dui auctor, quis molestie sem suscipit. Quisque eu ligula nisl. Ut sit amet viverra eros. Vivamus commodo odio orci, non pulvinar lacus egestas non. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse porttitor vestibulum diam ac dignissim. Donec et dolor faucibus, luctus magna lacinia, maximus mi. Proin vehicula, justo a fermentum rutrum, sem est sollicitudin dui, et euismod diam augue et odio. Mauris ac interdum felis. Quisque a auctor leo, sit amet sodales leo. Duis nec augue volutpat, convallis odio non, sagittis nulla.</p>
<p>Morbi id dapibus lorem. Maecenas id dignissim magna. Mauris laoreet nulla ut massa vulputate consequat. Morbi consectetur malesuada est, tempus vehicula mauris dignissim euismod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pretium neque quis ante vehicula eleifend. Vestibulum eu euismod sapien. Integer tempor sagittis sapien at fermentum.</p>
<p>Cras rhoncus tristique aliquet. Mauris id massa et enim pulvinar consectetur quis et sapien. Duis cursus faucibus elit eget dignissim. Nulla rutrum libero quis sapien luctus, sit amet fermentum turpis aliquet. Quisque in ex eu odio fringilla euismod tincidunt at nisi. Aenean imperdiet laoreet leo non mollis. Fusce venenatis neque leo, non sollicitudin nulla ultricies commodo. Sed ac mollis lectus, nec pharetra mauris. Curabitur hendrerit felis nisl, at molestie justo rhoncus sit amet. Vestibulum scelerisque, justo quis eleifend vulputate, elit diam finibus lectus, at sodales orci erat nec ipsum. Sed tempor libero vitae rhoncus porta. Cras ac lacinia diam. Fusce pharetra sit amet nunc a maximus. Nunc luctus justo laoreet sapien mattis, sit amet condimentum nisl tincidunt.</p>
<p>Duis sit amet tellus eu nulla hendrerit congue at vel est. In in enim nisl. Integer in pulvinar nunc. Sed faucibus, nulla sed congue interdum, ante ante eleifend velit, ut venenatis lorem ipsum nec lectus. Quisque eget erat a arcu consequat pharetra. Aenean venenatis dui ac odio viverra, nec viverra sem venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sodales nulla posuere pharetra interdum. Quisque justo erat, vestibulum eu purus sit amet, accumsan vulputate nisi. Morbi ultrices elit eu ligula mollis gravida.</p>
<p>Etiam a sollicitudin elit. Fusce eleifend ex ut luctus tincidunt. Ut dapibus ante ut mauris viverra malesuada. Donec euismod purus ac dolor auctor dapibus. Integer gravida consequat nisi, vitae rhoncus eros dictum ut. Sed pretium purus in libero convallis, id commodo arcu elementum. In lacinia nunc vel ligula imperdiet, ac placerat elit condimentum. Proin id ligula et libero fermentum mollis. Quisque tempus posuere felis et tincidunt. Donec sit amet sapien rhoncus, maximus orci sit amet, faucibus orci. Aliquam bibendum ligula elit, eget ultricies dui pretium eu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>
<p>Suspendisse accumsan magna vitae mauris scelerisque, eget faucibus odio accumsan. Donec condimentum mauris velit, id rhoncus mauris lobortis sed. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus nec lorem a sapien lacinia finibus. Phasellus consequat finibus massa ut interdum. Vivamus fermentum a felis maximus luctus. Sed cursus metus velit, id placerat nisi lacinia a.</p>
<p>Donec quis sapien lectus. Integer hendrerit nisl in dolor egestas, ac dictum elit volutpat. Cras eget massa aliquam, tincidunt sapien id, lacinia ex. Nam vitae justo sem. Aliquam nibh turpis, aliquam eget dui at, molestie bibendum erat. Aenean et lectus leo. Morbi metus ligula, venenatis sed egestas id, semper at ex. Nulla et interdum ligula. Sed blandit mollis finibus. In vitae vulputate est. Vivamus quis aliquam nisi, sed cursus ex. Pellentesque quis libero rutrum, sodales ipsum sed, tempus est. Phasellus posuere justo in nibh hendrerit consequat.</p>
<p>Cras finibus, neque ut placerat euismod, nulla neque placerat dolor, at maximus metus enim nec erat. Nam eu bibendum sem. Nunc porttitor aliquam justo sit amet porta. Aenean eu justo ut quam facilisis egestas et vel lorem. Vestibulum aliquam tortor feugiat erat fermentum commodo. Curabitur quis ultricies mauris. Etiam tempor dolor vitae nunc cursus, ut dictum tellus pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque consectetur nisi sit amet nisi pulvinar mattis. Aenean quis facilisis velit. Integer eu consectetur nulla. Duis sed nunc sed dui accumsan feugiat. Ut vulputate dictum justo.</p>
<p>Integer tempor malesuada massa, eu rhoncus ligula feugiat eget. Duis in ante lorem. Suspendisse euismod, massa at ullamcorper lacinia, metus odio condimentum ante, ac euismod mauris justo a dui. Praesent id diam at enim tristique laoreet. Aliquam accumsan laoreet vulputate. Nunc dignissim lorem ut neque interdum, non faucibus nisi congue. Donec ac luctus ante. Cras consequat et risus placerat faucibus. Aenean porta ex nec metus lacinia feugiat. Vivamus molestie feugiat malesuada. Donec convallis, purus sed vehicula volutpat, nibh lectus eleifend erat, sit amet convallis dolor erat at leo. Nulla ullamcorper, libero vel bibendum lacinia, dui velit posuere nisi, ac venenatis tellus sem eget ligula.</p>
<p>Pellentesque pellentesque elementum nulla, ultricies sagittis est molestie sit amet. Cras eget tortor egestas, mattis urna nec, fringilla dolor. Quisque convallis elit non velit tempus pretium. Ut blandit neque nec neque tristique, eu fermentum ligula dignissim. Vestibulum id euismod tellus, id consectetur nisl. Nulla maximus mauris ut cursus imperdiet. Ut ac egestas nibh. Morbi sit amet arcu vel dolor luctus viverra. Pellentesque at enim in ipsum commodo interdum. Sed ac tincidunt odio. Phasellus at odio nisl. Sed sed augue vel quam elementum egestas eget quis sem. Integer porttitor dolor id nisl vehicula, in tincidunt lacus dapibus. Sed euismod tortor in mi consectetur volutpat.</p>
<p>Phasellus cursus placerat rutrum. Vivamus sit amet nibh nec nisl rhoncus tincidunt. In id porttitor lacus, a vestibulum neque. In pulvinar, nisl et scelerisque pharetra, diam tellus sodales leo, semper dapibus orci leo non nisl. Duis et interdum mi, eget volutpat dui. Integer sit amet vestibulum dolor. Donec varius facilisis velit, in porta purus tincidunt sit amet. Vestibulum eu est sodales, maximus purus in, sagittis nisi. Quisque at scelerisque lacus. Aliquam dignissim erat non volutpat rutrum. Nulla ac euismod augue, ac tempus nibh. Vivamus venenatis, quam a rhoncus commodo, nisl turpis congue velit, nec iaculis mi magna tincidunt urna.</p>
<p>Nulla at mi nunc. Integer tincidunt maximus erat in feugiat. Donec eget malesuada lectus. Aenean nec lorem sit amet ex luctus lacinia a vel leo. Integer porta accumsan accumsan. Vestibulum ac diam eget arcu blandit accumsan. Curabitur eu porta ligula. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris fringilla, nibh sit amet lacinia elementum, ligula diam vulputate mauris, a ornare sapien nisi consectetur nibh.</p>
<p>Quisque eu ex egestas, consequat purus a, imperdiet diam. Cras imperdiet metus vel dolor dapibus, ac pulvinar nunc elementum. Fusce eget iaculis leo, at volutpat erat. Integer tincidunt tellus ac aliquam pulvinar. Vivamus hendrerit mi non sem interdum suscipit. Vestibulum ut molestie nunc. Quisque lacus felis, cursus eu mi sed, varius facilisis urna. In pulvinar, risus vel consequat pharetra, mauris elit laoreet turpis, quis semper orci felis pulvinar ante. Maecenas tincidunt dui turpis, in varius quam facilisis et. Duis eu odio et ligula dapibus tempor. Donec feugiat libero eu luctus eleifend. Nam porta dapibus tellus ut aliquam.</p>
<p>Aliquam ut metus vel nisl laoreet congue. Mauris neque nisi, tempor a lacus nec, tincidunt volutpat massa. Morbi sed auctor augue, quis tempor quam. Nam eget nunc turpis. Integer rutrum dolor et tellus hendrerit ornare. Donec imperdiet feugiat tristique. Praesent egestas at sem nec pharetra. Aenean lectus justo, aliquet in urna quis, finibus pretium ex. Curabitur rhoncus fringilla pellentesque. Nunc congue volutpat eros at dictum. Etiam vel odio molestie, tincidunt turpis vitae, imperdiet nisi. Nullam diam eros, lacinia nec tristique a, fermentum id risus. Curabitur lobortis arcu non nulla elementum vehicula.</p>
<p>Fusce sed rhoncus justo. Donec sit amet feugiat mi. Aenean ultrices velit vitae bibendum commodo. Sed ut interdum massa. Duis quis hendrerit risus. Donec mollis odio ut sapien ornare volutpat. Sed sed luctus velit. Cras eleifend interdum arcu in vulputate. Etiam tempus lacus ut odio congue convallis. Nam tincidunt id nulla in consequat.</p>
      <!-- Контент  -->
    </div>

  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want the scrollbar on the whole page, just inside the content right?

You could achieve this like that:

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar{
  height: 120px; // or any height you want to your navbar
  // your other styles
}
.content{
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  // your other styles
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To scroll only an element you need to use
`overflow:hidden` in the container and `overflow:auto` just for the scrollable content, as @satyr has responded.

to set the scollable element in a non scrollable full page you need to setup your html and body to cover the full page, as @cs.matyi has responded.

So a complex layout with both scrollable and fixed elements you need to combine both techniques, resulting something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Layout</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .flexvertical {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .flexhorizontal {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    .space-between {
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .align-center {
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .overflow-hidden {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .overflow-auto {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .padding {
      padding: 1rem;
    }
    
    .reverse {
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="flexvertical">
  <header class="flexhorizontal space-between align-center reverse padding">
    <img src="https://imageholdr.com/220x60/transparent/84c286?text=layout&font-size=32&font-family=stiljaFree">
    <h1>Layout test</h1>
    <nav><a href="/">Home</a> | <a href="#">Things</a> | <a href="#">Stranger things</a> | <a href="#">Other things</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="flexvertical overflow-hidden">

    <h1 class="padding">Page Heading</h1>

    <article class="padding overflow-auto">
      <h2>Article heading</h2>
      <p>Scrollable Article content</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto
      </p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto
      </p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto
      </p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto
      </p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto
      </p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Impedit aliquid sequi iusto alias modi distinctio tempora, consectetur, rerum libero eligendi, voluptatum expedita debitis est sunt praesentium facilis excepturi. Eveniet, itaque. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Quod aspernatur, non nesciunt recusandae, temporibus consectetur lorem harum ullam provident iste laboriosam porro nulla est necessitatibus placeat cum unde ut, architecto
      </p>
    </article>
  </main>
  <footer class="reverse padding">
    Copyright &copy; 2023. All Rights Reserved.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```